# Check date inside a html code

Tags: java, html, date, parsing, jsoup

I have a webpage with a label like that: "Table last updated on Thu Jul 27 10:57:10 CEST 2017 from OWNER"

I have to check if this date is later than 0h today.
I'm getting the html code with:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(driver.getPageSource());
String htmlcode = doc.body().text();
```

I thought about substringing the code to get the date, but since this label value can vary in size, I could not get the whole label.
Any ideas on how to get the date from the code, so I can compare it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (prior to `Java 8`):

```
    // get the label content as text (assuming you only have 1 label)
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(driver.getPageSource());
    Element label = doc.select("label").first();
    String labelText = label.text();

    // get the relevant part (the date) from label content (between "on" and "from")
    String dateString = labelText.split("on")[1].split("from")[0].trim();

    // parse date
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    java.util.Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString);

    // create calendar from label date
    Calendar calendarLabel = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendarLabel.setTime(date);

    // create calendar for beginning of today in the default time zone
    //Calendar calendarToday = Calendar.getInstance();
    //  or in a timezone of your choice
    Calendar calendarToday = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Athens"));
    calendarToday.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendarToday.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendarToday.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendarToday.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    // find out if label date is later than 0h of today
    System.out.println(calendarLabel.compareTo(calendarToday) >= 1);
```

For a more succinct solution in `Java 8`, see [this answer of  Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45596007/2736843).

Comment: This code uses troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. Another problem: This code assumes the day starts at 00:00:00 which is *not* always true for all dates on all zones.

Comment: @Basil Bourque I agree I missed some details by assuming that all dates are in the same zone and that there are newer classes to use in `Java 8`. I have updated my answer, thanks for bringing up all these concerns! Also I upvoted your answer.

Comment: Not to be picking on you, but 3-4 letter pseudo-zones like `CET` are *not* actual time zones. They are not standardized. They are not even unique! [Real time zone names](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) are in the format of `continent/region` such as `Asia/Kolkata` or `Pacific/Auckland` or [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca).

Comment: No problem, I was never aware of it. I will update my answer accordingly. It is very confusing in any case, as `CEST` is also used in the html example above as a valid time zone.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.parse(                              // Parse string into a date + time-of-day + time zone.
    … ,                                           // Your input string.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz uuuu" , Locale.US )  // Specify `Locale` to determine human language and cultural norms in parsing and translating the text.    
)
.toLocalDate()                                    // Extract the date-only portion of the `ZonedDateTime` object.
.isEqual( 
    LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )  // Get current date as seen by people of a certain region (time zone).
)
```

## java.time

The [Answer by aUserHimself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45594728/642706) is correct in suggesting the use of jsoup library.  But the example code is ill-advised in other ways, making these few mistakes:

- Using troublesome legacy date-time classes. Those classes are now supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.
- Assumes the day starts at 00:00:00. Not true for all dates in all time zones. Anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) mean the day may start at a time such as 01:00:00.
- Ignoring the issue of [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html), which determines the human language used in parsing the text of the name of month, name of day-of-week, etc. The [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) also determines the expected punctuation and other cultural norms.
- Ignores the crucial issue of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) in determining the current date.

Example code.

```
String input = … ;
Locale locale = Locale.US ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz uuuu" , locale ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Compare to today's date. Must specify the expected/desired time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the world by zone. A new day dawns earlier in India than in Canada, for example.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ; 
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;

Boolean isSameDate = ld.isEqual( today ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

With a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) complying with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings or java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).